# OpenCV and Libpng library error

Tags: android, opencv, libpng

[image: Libpng Error]

I made one App like scanner in this i use Scanlibrary **jhansireddy** from github. It works fine but when i make signed and upload it on Google Play it gives above error.

I already updates **Libpng library version 1.6.xx.** I also updated **OpenCv dependancy version 3.1.** Still I Got this Error. Can anybody find what the problem is??

Comment: You may raise an issue for the same on the Github repo as well.

Comment: Then here is a link for [submitting issue](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo/issues/new) in this repo

Comment: yes..it solved by updating libpng library and openCV..